# Does this set up for my app make sense?

Tags: android

First off, I'm totally brand new to any kind of coding.  I started trying to make an app with App Inventor, but it became too big for that and couldn't do exactly what I was wanting.  So now I'm attempting to do it all from scratch.

I think I'm getting things figured out, but I'd like to check and see if this makes sense before I got and build the whole thing.

What I'm aiming for is a main screen with a bunch of buttons on it.  Each of those buttons will take you to a set of directions that is a series of pictures and text that you can flip through.

What I'm thinking is to make an activity for the main screen and one for each set of directions.  On the main one, I put a table layout which contains all the buttons.  Each of the directions sets will be its own activity with a view flipper to go through all the pics/text.

Does that make sense?  Is there a better way to do this or is this good?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there are two activities.  Your main activity with the set of buttons and a second activity that displays a set of instructions and images.  Just build your activity so, based on how it is launched from your main application it reads the information to be displayed.

Edit: Details

To be honest, this is a pretty broad software design question.  You want to separate the *what* you are displaying from the *how* you are displaying it.

I'm going to loosely refer to your content as pages (text and images).  This is the *what* when we talk about your applications data.  What you want to do is further define this into something like an object:

```
public class PageData implements Serializable {
   String imageUrl;
   String description;
}

public class Book implements Serializable {
  ArrayList<PageData> swipeablePages;
}
```

When you invoke your Activity to display a set of pages, you'd pass the Book as a extra to the intent.  Your activity is then written generically to just display whatever book is sent to it.  This reduces the number of different Activities you have greatly because now, you no longer need to have your Activity say 'I'm Mother Goose Nursery Rhymes" ... instead it just says "I can display any book you throw at me" and your main activity now could have a book shelf of 30 books.  The main activity creates the books and shows an index and your second activity displays and allows users to interact with a book.

The sky is really the limit.  Lets say you create the most entertaining book experience ever on android.  You could now publish your intent as "content:mybookdisplayer" and explain to other developers what books should look like.  Then other developers could use your book viewer and heap praise on you for your piece of work!  You could even embed an add on your book viewer and make millions of dollars :)  Anyway, it all starts with dividing the *what* from the *how*.  If you get that separation down, I think you'll find that your code is more reusable and easier to maintain.

Comment: I accept. But to elaborate on this answer, the second activity will have a textview and imageview. While creating the intent for the startactivity, put details on the text and the image to be displayed on the intent bundle. In the second activity get the intent (getIntent) and read the bundle extra for text and image value and set it. (One more thing Text and image column name should be a public static constant. ) Let me know if you need more details? (since you mentioned that you are new to programming)

Comment: Yes, more details would be useful.

Comment: Opps, didn't mean to send that...  The second activity (and there will actually be many of these, one for each set of directions) has a View Flipper and for each "page" of the View Flipper, there is an Image View and a Text View.

Answer (score 1):

Your method makes sense but can be improved.  For a beginners point of view it would appear easier to make seperate activities for each of the different directions set.

In the future you could possibly break this down into two activities.  The first one as you outlined but the second would differ.

The second activity would contain the code to flip through data but the data itself will differ.  You can use something called extras.  See [Common Tasks and How to Do Them in Android - Some Intent examples](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen)

You launch the second intent/activity with data that can be used to identify which button the user pressed and in the second activity, read this value.

You would have to make arrays in the second activity for each of the direction sets, then depending on the option the user selected, apply the data from these arrays to the users display/view.

However, for a beginner your idea seems perfect.  Get used to the new environment and tools then start looking into more advanced methods.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad to see I'm at least  somewhat on the right track.